# How to use a file as artifact from early stage in Docker multi-stage build in another job?

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a gitlab build pipeline which builds a docker image on x86 and on s390x with 2 jobs (stages). Due to technical problems outside the scope of this question I am forced to re-use a file from the x86 job later in the s390x job (architecture independent). I want to achieve this by defining an artifact with that filename.

The x86 job is multi-stage to save space. The intermediate file I will later need for s390x is created in the "builder" stage and not needed in the docker image at runtime later on.

How can I use this (tar) file as an artifact in the 2nd job for s390x?

This is from .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - amd64
  - s390x

docker-build-amd64:
  variables:
    ARCH: x86_64
    DOCKER_PULL_IMAGE: library/node:16
  image: ${RUNNER_IMAGE}
  stage: amd64
  services:
    - ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/docker:18.09.7-dind
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /app.tar
    expire_in: 1 hour
  script:
    - >
      docker build
...
docker-build-s390x:
  variables:
    ARCH: s390x
    DOCKER_PULL_IMAGE: node:16
  stage: s390x
  tags:
    - s390x
    - shell
  script:
    - >
      podman build --rm
      --format docker
...
```

Here's a snippet from the Dockerfile:

```
# Builder
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY
ARG DOCKER_PULL_IMAGE
FROM $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_PULL_IMAGE as builder

...
RUN tar -C /src -cf /app.tar webapp

# App
FROM $DOCKER_REGISTRY/nginx:alpine

COPY --from=builder /src/webapp /app
# from builder stage, will be artifact towards s390x job
RUN ls -l /app.tar
```